# Power BI resource exceeded issue

Tags: powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I'm getting this error in power bi service and desktop when adding columns to my table visual.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7mg2.png)

In my table there are more than 100 columns. is there a visual limitation? what can I do to solve this issue and client doesn't like to change the format also. so he needs all the columns in a one table visual.

Can anyone please give a solution to this.

I need to add and show all these columns in a one table visual.